# Ubuntu 16.04 Terminal SSH Client slow - compare to Windows Putty SSH Client

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I have two "client" PCs at the same location, accessing AWS-based Ubuntu 14 standard image machines' terminals via ssh. One "client" box is Ubuntu 16 and another Windows 8.

On Windows client, I use a standard download putty 0.63, SSH radio button for Connection Type, Private Key File authentication pointing to my .ppk file.

On Ubuntu client, also standard config as OS installed, I use the terminal and "ssh -i " to get to the AWS machine's terminal.

The putty window flies, just as I'm working with my local files and processes. The Ubuntu ssh terminal connection is slow, and periodically hangs for a few seconds.

As both "client" machines are on the exact same network - there is something with ssh setup on the Ubuntu box that makes it painfully mis-performing compare to the Windows-Putty client. I've upgraded client ssh to hpn-ssh and set up TCP and ssh options per suggestions; I use "-x" and "-C" - nothing helps, really.

E.g., as I type "sudo" and hit space the terminal stops for a fraction of a second before jumping the space. Similarly, cursor movements inside, e.g., vim freeze periodically, especially, after some time working.
The putty log is below. I'm wondering how to make OpenSSH to behave similarly, or is there another recommended ssh tool I should rather use on Ubuntu client to ssh effectively to an AWS-based Ubuntu instance?

`2016-09-26 17:34:18    Looking up host "52.32.3.xxx"
2016-09-26 17:34:18 Connecting to 52.32.3.xxx port 22
2016-09-26 17:34:18 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
2016-09-26 17:34:18 Using SSH protocol version 2
2016-09-26 17:34:18 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63
2016-09-26 17:34:18 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2016-09-26 17:34:18 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
2016-09-26 17:34:20 Host key fingerprint is:
2016-09-26 17:34:20 ssh-rsa 2048 ...:...:...
2016-09-26 17:34:20 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2016-09-26 17:34:20 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2016-09-26 17:34:20 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2016-09-26 17:34:20 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
2016-09-26 17:34:20 Reading private key file "C:\Users\...\AWSSetup.ppk"
2016-09-26 17:34:23 Offered public key
2016-09-26 17:34:23 Offer of public key accepted
2016-09-26 17:34:23 Sent public key signature
2016-09-26 17:34:23 Access granted
2016-09-26 17:34:23 Opening session as main channel
2016-09-26 17:34:23 Opened main channel
2016-09-26 17:34:23 Local port 8080 SOCKS dynamic forwarding
2016-09-26 17:34:24 Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
2016-09-26 17:34:24 Started a shell/command`

Comment: Have you tried tcpdump/wireshark on the Ubuntu client to see if there's packet loss?

Comment: Wumpus, thank you for pointing me in this direction. tcpdump shows periodic "retries" on packets sent out to the AWS VM, and as there is a packet for each key stroke on the client terminal - the fact that Ack don't come back sometimes for half a second or so may cause the delay, I assume.

Comment: <continuing> A "bizarre" thing is that when I run "sudo mtr <AWS VM IP> in another terminal window on my PC - the SSH dialog, overs sudden, works perfectly fast. mtr shows ~1% avg packet loss at selected hubs, but it appears that when I continuously bombard the target with packets (as mtr does) - the SSH connection's speed skyrockets. Not sure now what setting would emulate this effect without mtr running? Any ideas?